# What font might this be?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm designing a website for a client for which I need to redesign his (same) logo based up on the scanned letter head. I'm not that good at identifying fonts. Can anyone kindly tell what might this font might be?

[image]

**EDIT:** I tried automated font identification but it no fruitful result.

Comment: Have you already tried the automated services?

Comment: No! Are there any automatic font detection softwares?

Comment: Check out the tag wiki for [font-identification](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info)

Comment: please check this service out:
http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: If it's a logo it may be hand-drawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Revue.

http://www.searchfreefonts.com/font/revue.htm

Comment: Lauren Ipsum you rock!

Comment: wow. Designer: Colin Brignall - Year: 1969

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the automated font identification is not giving any results. This font looks quite familiar (must have been very popular in the 90s), but I can't remember the name.

If you are redesigning the logo, then you might consider choosing or drawing a new typo. If you are stuck with this one, you can try:

1) Looking for classic 90s fonts lists and going one by one until you locate the one,

2) Redrawing it yourself. It's not likely that you are going to use this font for anything else but the logo, so having it in vectors is more than enough.

Good luck!